Why do we integrate the momentum states from 0 to infinity to get the partition function?
Suppose we have a gas of classical free particles with total finite energy $E$.To get the partition function of a single particle, we integrate over the momentum states from 0 to $\infty$ as $$ Z=\frac{V}{h^{3}}\int_ {0}^{\infty} d^3{\mathbf p} \exp \left[ - \frac{|{\mathbf p}_i |^2}{2mk_B T}\right]\ $$
(V bieng the total voulme).
This doesn't make sense to me, as it would imply that we are including particle states with infinite energy. The probability factor $ \ e^ {-\beta \epsilon}\ $ goes to zero as $\epsilon$ tends to $\infty$, but what about other finite-energy states that are greater in energy than our predefined total energy $E$?why do we count them?

"we are including particle states with infinite energy" That is not true. Infinity is not a real number and is therefore not a possible value for the energy.

It could be instructive to think first about the microcanonical ensemble: $Z(E)=\int dp_1...dp_N\delta(\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{p_i^2}{2m}-E)$ - sure, we integrate over all states, but we choose only those, that satisfy our constraint. Boltzmann partition function can be viewed as an approximation obtained by writing a microcanonical partition function for system+thermostat, and integrating out the thermostat. Although an approximation, it works to a very high degree of precision, due to very small probabilities of extremely high energy states. (In thermodynamic limit, the result becomes exact)

@MichaelSeifert If you want to post your answer, now would be the time.

@MichaelSeifert so if i calculate the number of microstates,exponential term not bieng would require to integrate the phase cells from $ p=0 $ to $ p=\sqrt{2mE}\ $

Normally when we discuss the partition function, we are implicitly looking at the states of a "small" system in thermal contact with a "large" (effectively infinite) reservoir at a temperature $T$.  This reservoir is assumed to be sufficiently large that its temperature is constant, regardless of the amount of energy that it absorbs from or gives to the "small" system.
In the standard treatment of the classical ideal gas, the "small" system is a single gas molecule and the "reservoir" is the remainder of the gas molecules.  It is true that the reservoir is not infinite in this case, and that we would never expect the "system" to get more energy than the total energy $U$ of the gas.  However, in the "pure" Boltzmann distribution, any state where a single gas molecule has an energy that's much more than a few times $kT$ is exponentially suppressed anyhow, and so doesn't contribute very much to the partition function anyhow.  So long as $U \gg kT$, we can therefore get a good approximation to the partition function by treating the reservoir as infinite;  the only difference would be in the predicted probabilities of the high-energy states, and those are so unlikely that they should not affect the behavior of our system in any meaningful way.

sir,how do we know this approximation doesnt effect the rest of the calculation that are to be derived from the partition function?In simple words,how do we know the partition function we got from this approximation is the one we were looking for?
